# Passing any control as an argument of function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function, user-controls, argument-passing

I want to make a common function which takes a control as an argument (like UITextField, UIButton etc.)

Its working fine if I do like this

```
- (void)  myFunction : (UITextField*) : control
{

}

//But I want to make it common for any control

- (void)  myFunction : (`I don't know what to write here`) : control
{
     //suppose if control is UITextField, I can set its font and its size.
     //something like this
    [control setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go like this

```
- (void)  myFunction : (id) control
{
  if([control isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
     // Your textfield condition
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `UIControl`, since it's the super class for the controls.

Then in your code, you should use methods like `respondsToSelector:` to determine whether or not the control passed in can do what you need it to do.

You could check its class type using `isKindOfClass:` or `isMemberOfClass` as well.

Once you know which object you're dealing with, you could type cast it to save on some typing and remove any warnings about not responding to selectors, like this:

```
// decided that it's a UITextField after using `respondsToSelector:` or `isKindOfClass:`
UITextField *aTextField = (UITextField *)control;
```

This method is known as "duck-typing" - since it's similar to saying "If it walks like a duck and sounds like a duck, it'll probably be a duck".

Answer (score 0):

`UIControl` is the superclass of `UITextField`, `UIButton`, and other controls, so this is what you want:

```
- (void) myFunction:(UIControl *) control
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. You can pass UIView as an argument like Below

```
- (void)  myFunction:(UIView*)customView{
   if([customView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
     // This is UIImageview
  }
}
```

Hope this Help.

Answer (score 0):

use generic ID then cast your control and ask if it's a UITextField (or subclass of...)

```
   - (void)  myFunction : (id)  control
    {
         //suppose if control is UITextField, I can set its font and its size.
         //something like this
        (UITextField*)aText = (UITextField*)control;
        if ([aText.class isSubclassOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [aText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
        }
    }
```